# How to keep the GIT repos in sync

Tags: git

I don’t grasp GIT yet. So I have a basic question:

I want to keep one of the repos that I am using (I don’t own it, I cloned it)
in sync with my local copy.

How do I do that?

I am aware of git fetch/pull but when I do run that in the same folder where I executed git clone http://.....git I get the following error

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of
>   the parent directories): .git

Thanks,
mE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git fetch` will retrieve all changes from the remote.

`git pull` will merge those changes from the remote into your local copy (this accomplishes two commands in one step. `fetch & merge`

If you have commit access to the remote repository, `git push` will push your local changes to the origin that you cloned from.

Comment: when I do that I get an error, like this: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git  -- and I do run the command in the same path where I did the git clone

Comment: @amok Are you in the directory that was cloned? What do you see when you type 'git status'?

Answer (score 2):

Git clone creates a new directory for cloned repo. You need to go into it first. For example:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/git/hello-world.git
$ cd hello-world
$ git fetch
```

Comment: git fetch does not merge in the master's updates into your local copy! You want git pull (see higher voted answer, below)

Comment: He only wanted to solve "Not a git repository" problem

Answer (score 0):

Git fetch will download all of the changes that exist on the remote, but won't update your working tree. Git pull will download changes and if you're on a local branch tracking a remote branch, will update it for you.